# How do I get rid of this stupid system tray utility?

Tags: unity, system-tray, notification-area

By default, Ubuntu hides all but a few of the system tray icons in Ubuntu's notification area. A while ago I had a reason to want the hidden ones to show up, so I installed a utility that shows the hidden icons under their own drop-down menu in the system tray.

I no longer want this utility around, as it doesn't play nice with multiple monitors (I now have a keyboard icon permanantly blocking the menu bar), but I have a problem:

I can't remember what this utility is called, and I don't know what starts it, so I don't know how to remove it. The utility itself is very minimal and doesn't tell you what its name is from the user interface.

Comment: to do anyhting you need to know the package name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like [Indicator Systemtray Unity](https://github.com/GGleb/indicator-systemtray-unity). Try to remove the package `indicator-systemtray-unity`